# image upload not working when changing upload button from input to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following image upload script:

```
function upload_media_async(form_name, media_type, file_path, file_url, file_embed, nb_uploads, max_uploads, upload_id) {
   var radio_buttons = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < form_name.length; i++) {
      if (form_name.elements[i].type == 'radio' && form_name.elements[i].checked == true) {
         radio_buttons[form_name.elements[i].name] = form_name.elements[i].value;
      }
   }

   var jsHttp = new JsHttpRequest();
   var xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

   if (jsHttp == null) {
      alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
   }

   var media_name = '';
   switch (media_type) {
      case 1:
         media_name = 'ad_image';
         break;
      case 2:
         media_name = 'ad_video';
         break;
      case 3:
         media_name = 'ad_dd';
         break;
   }

   var media_box_name = 'display_media_boxes_' + media_name;

   file_embed = base64Encode(file_embed);
   var url = relative_path + 'ajax_files/upload_file.php';
   var action = url + '?do=add&media_type=' + media_type + '&file_url=' + file_url +
           '&file_embed=' + file_embed + '&nb_uploads=' + nb_uploads + '&upload_id=' + upload_id;

   var thumbnail_div = document.getElementById('display_media_boxes_' + media_name);
   var new_content = document.createElement('div');

   if (file_embed != '') {
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

            var results = response.split('|');

            if (results[5] != '') {
               alert(results[5]);
            }
            else {
               new_content.innerHTML = results[3];

               while (new_content.firstChild) {
                  thumbnail_div.appendChild(new_content.firstChild);
               }

               var hidden_div = document.getElementById('hidden_media_boxes');
               var hidden_content = document.createElement('div');
               hidden_content.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="' + results[1] + '[]" id="hidden_' + results[2] + '" value="' + results[4] + '">';

               while (hidden_content.firstChild) {
                  hidden_div.appendChild(hidden_content.firstChild);
               }
               nb_uploads++;
            }

//                document.getElementById('div_file_' + media_type).innerHTML = document.getElementById('div_file_' + media_type).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).value = '';
            document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).value = '';

            if (nb_uploads >= max_uploads) {
               document.getElementById('btn_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).disabled = true;
            }
            document.getElementById('nb_uploads_' + media_type).value = nb_uploads;
         }
      };
      xmlHttp.open("POST", action, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
   else {
      jQuery.blockUI({message: '<p style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;">' + upl_progress_msg + '</p>'});

      var image_loading = document.createElement('div');
      image_loading.innerHTML = '<img src="' + relative_path + 'images/loading-media.gif">';
      thumbnail_div.appendChild(image_loading);

      jsHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (jsHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var response = jsHttp.responseText;

            var results = response.split('|');

            if (results[5] != '') {
               alert(results[5]);
               thumbnail_div.removeChild(image_loading);
               setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI, 500);
            }
            else {
               new_content.innerHTML = results[3];

               while (new_content.firstChild) {
                  thumbnail_div.replaceChild(new_content.firstChild, image_loading);
               }
               setTimeout(jQuery.unblockUI, 500);

               var hidden_div = document.getElementById('hidden_media_boxes');
               var hidden_content = document.createElement('div');
               hidden_content.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="' + results[1] + '[]" id="hidden_' + results[2] + '" value="' + results[4] + '">';

               while (hidden_content.firstChild) {
                  hidden_div.appendChild(hidden_content.firstChild);
               }
               nb_uploads++;
            }

//                document.getElementById('div_file_' + media_type).innerHTML = document.getElementById('div_file_' + media_type).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).value = '';
            document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).value = '';

            if (nb_uploads >= max_uploads) {
               document.getElementById('btn_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_upload_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_url_' + media_type).disabled = true;
               document.getElementById('item_file_embed_' + media_type).disabled = true;
            }
            document.getElementById('nb_uploads_' + media_type).value = nb_uploads;

            for (var i = 0; i < form_name.length; i++) {
               if (form_name.elements[i].type == 'radio' && radio_buttons[form_name.elements[i].name] == form_name.elements[i].value) {
                  form_name.elements[i].checked = true;
               }
            }
         }
      };

      jsHttp.open("POST", action, true);
      jsHttp.send({file: file_path});
   }
}
```

This works fine when using this HTML:

```
<div id="div_file_1">
<input name="item_file_upload_1" id="item_file_upload_1" style="width: 250px;"
onchange="upload_media_async(ad_create_form, 1, 
this.form.item_file_upload_1, 
document.getElementById('item_file_url_1').value, 
document.getElementById('item_file_embed_1').value, 
document.getElementById('nb_uploads_1').value, 
5, 
'A_571');" type="file">
</div>
```

Now, I am wrapping the INPUT in a SPAN in order to style it:

```
<div id="div_file_1">
<span class="btn btn-file" name="item_file_upload_1" 
id="item_file_upload_1" style="width: 250px;" 
onchange="upload_media_async(ad_create_form, 1, 
this.form.item_file_upload_1, 
document.getElementById('item_file_url_1').value, 
document.getElementById('item_file_embed_1').value, 
document.getElementById('nb_uploads_1').value, 
5, 
'A_571');">
<input type="file">
</span>
</div>
```

And suddenly the upload doesn't work anymore. When I click to select a file, it does nothing ...it just sits there. What do I have to change in order to make it work even with the SPAN wrapped around the INPUT?

Comment: Oh, that's bad ...so there's pretty much no way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you just style the input element?

Comment: Also, elements without are proper closing tag, are called self-closing, they need a slash at the end to close themselves: `<input type="file" />`. (The space before the closing tag is no accident, that is the proper way.)

Comment: @myfunkyside: file input elements can't be styled...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/v9ux7dy2/

Answer (score 0):

In `this.form.item_file_upload_1`, `this` refers to the span. Therefore `this.form` is undefined. We need to access the form another way. You'll also need to move the `name` and `id` back to their `<input>`. That should get you on the right path.